# C# Rename Registry value errors "returned null"

Tags: c#, function, registry

So to my final programming project I need to rename a value inside Registry through C#, this is what I wrote so far:

```
public bool RenameSubKey(string parentKey, string subKeyName, string newSubKeyName)
    {
        if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        {
            RegistryKey rk64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
            rk64.OpenSubKey(parentKey);

            //copy all the values
            foreach (string valueName in rk64.OpenSubKey(subKeyName).GetValueNames())
            {
                object objValue = rk64.OpenSubKey(subKeyName).GetValue(valueName);
                RegistryValueKind valKind = rk64.OpenSubKey(subKeyName).GetValueKind(valueName);
                rk64.CreateSubKey(newSubKeyName).SetValue(valueName, objValue, valKind);
            }

            rk64.DeleteSubKeyTree(subKeyName); // Deletes old value

            return true;
        }

        using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(parentKey, false))
        {
            rk.OpenSubKey(parentKey);

            //copy all the values
            foreach (string valueName in rk.OpenSubKey(subKeyName).GetValueNames())
            {
                object objValue = rk.OpenSubKey(subKeyName).GetValue(valueName);
                RegistryValueKind valKind = rk.OpenSubKey(subKeyName).GetValueKind(valueName);
                rk.CreateSubKey(newSubKeyName).SetValue(valueName, objValue, valKind);
            }

            rk.DeleteSubKeyTree(subKeyName); // Deletes old value

            return true;
        }
    }
```

It needs to be able to rename a 32-bit Registry value as well as a 64-bit Registry value (the application is 32-bit). Rename function simply means to create new value with the new name, copy all the data from the old one to the new one and delete the old one.

Let's take an example: There's a ListView presents all the installed application on the PC and I want to change the value *UninstallString* to *!UninstallString* with the press of a button so the users won't be able to uninstall the selected application in the ListView. The app might be 64-bit (meaning the Registry values are 64-bit and it requires a little different approach) or it can be 32-bit - Hence comes the *if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)*.

So in the example I place *SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\7-Zip* as my path and I want to rename the value *UninstallString* to *!UninstallString*, but it quits on the **foreach** with an error says **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(...) returned null.**

Comment: Before actually giving you an answer, do you want to change a SubKey? Or do you actually want to change a single value?

Comment: @nalnpir Single value in this case

Comment: Then the whole approach is wrong, you are looking to change all the values inside a SubKey, what you actually want to do is to single out a key and change the value. I ll write an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@nalnpir** I fixed the *rename Registry value function*:

```
public static bool RenameSubKey(string path, string keyName, string newKeyName)
    {
        if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        {
            RegistryKey rk64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(path, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

            object objValue = rk64.GetValue(keyName);
            RegistryValueKind valKind = rk64.GetValueKind(keyName);

            rk64.SetValue(newKeyName, objValue, valKind);

            rk64.DeleteValue(keyName);

            return true;
        }

        using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
        {
            object objValue = rk.GetValue(keyName);
            RegistryValueKind valKind = rk.GetValueKind(keyName);

            rk.SetValue(newKeyName, objValue, valKind);

            rk.DeleteValue(keyName);

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Now I see that I didn't access it the right way (as he enlightened me) and thus was the error.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me say, this requieres elevated privileges, the changes are because you want to enter the registry and write in them so you need to actually tell that when you are opening the sub key. Either in 64 or 32 bit. Im not sure about the If, as pointed out before by the general, but this will work at least for 32 bits path

```
public static bool RenameSubKey(string parentKey, string key, string newValue)
{
    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
    {
        RegistryKey rk64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(parentKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

        rk64.SetValue(key, newValue);

        return true;
    }

    using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(parentKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
    {
        rk.SetValue(key, newValue);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! I’ll try that in the morning. Great to have people like you (willing to help on their own free time).

Comment: I been helped a lot with by this site, so its my own way to contribute the best i can

Comment: Once again, thanks a lot. Just something to clarify, it doesn’t copy the data from the old value. I’ll try to add it also in the morning. There are not enough words for me to thank you, even just for the time

Comment: No, it does not copy the value, it just write over it. The key itself doesnt change, you are changing the value of the key

Comment: Oh, so what I tried to do it to keep the value and just change the name of it.